# Defering the return of a function, in a fluent Javascript API

Tags: javascript

I'm building a little modal package, and I'd like to have a fluent api, one of things I'd like to do is be able to optionally pass an animation function into the close method and have the method called after it only run once that optional animation is complete.

a) I'm thinking about this correctly?
b) Should I just be using a callback?
c) is there an alternative to using a setTimeout?  (I don't know why this feels dirty but it does)
d) I suppose promises are an options but that would disrupt the syntax.

What I'd like to land up with is :

```
   Modal.save().close().resetData();
```

Comment: And what do you mean by *"derring"*, do you really mean deferring, and what do you mean by a *"fluent API"*, is it something special that is important here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) I'm thinking about this correctly?

Yes.

> b) Should I just be using a
>   callback?

Yes, no problem with that approach.

> c) is there an alternative to using a setTimeout? (I don't
>   know why this feels dirty but it does)

For the animation, either use CSS transitions or `requestAnimationFrame` rather than `setTimeout`.

> d) I suppose promises are an
>   options but that would disrupt the syntax.

You could refactor to promises when you have it working. Promises do offer a more fluent API.

With the callback approach, I'd expect it to look like this:

```
function close(done) {
  // do something async then call `done`
}

Modal.save(close.bind(Modal, resetData));
```

Comment: Thanks ben, thats helpful in getting started, regarding c) in using requestAnimationFrame and CSS transitions are you saying theres a way to know when the animation is complete?  or would I still be setting a timer of some kind?

Comment: When using RAF the end is obvious. I am unsure of css transition end events.